# How to register a sparklistener to work on spark worker process

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my spark jobs, there are some 3rd party libraries with various data, metrics, ...
When I create and register SparkListener it executes the callbacks code in a driver

My question how can i have some code that will be executed on a worker when worker is starting some stage, and also when it finished the stage ( run all tasks)? Or finisher a job?

I that case it will be a good trigger to extract some data from 3rd parties libs that actually running on workers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with 2.4 `Spark` has [Executor Plugin API](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24918)

[ExecutorPlugin](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/ExecutorPlugin.java)

> A plugin which can be automatically instantiated within each Spark executor.  Users can specify plugins which should be created with the "spark.executor.plugins" configuration. An instance of each plugin will be created for every executor, including those created by dynamic allocation,  before the executor starts running any tasks.

It [starts](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L150) at the very beginning before any task is got executed.

There is an example [project](https://github.com/squito/spark-memory) that aims to show some basic usage.
It uses a proposed design, the actual implementation is quite different.

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config("spark.executor.plugins", CustomPlugin.getClass.getName.replace("$", ""))
      .getOrCreate()
```

And the implementation:

```
object CustomPlugin extends ExecutorPlugin {

  override def init(): Unit = {
    println(s"Started")
    //Not that TaskContext.get() throws NPE as task context hasn't been initialized yet
  }

  override def shutdown(): Unit = {
    println(s"Shutdown:")
  }
}
```

Don't forget to stop the spark session at the end

```
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Note that this API has been completely refactored in Spark 3 -- there are now both Driver and Executor components, with optional RPC from Executor to Driver. Note also that the Executor-side `shutdown` is not guaranteed to ever run if the executor is teared down with SIGTERM _(i.e. YARN container is preempted, or job runs in Spark Standalone cluster)_

Comment: Very nice comment, thanks! I suppose besides preemption the task might fail with OOM in such case Spark stops the executor programmatically with System.exit (or even halt)