# how can i set spark.executor.plugins in pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python code in which i have some rdd function iwant to be distributed in multiple executors.

i want to be able to execute some python code(init a logger method) on each executor before the sparkish code runs. i read and found that this is possible by providing spark.executor.plugins when creating the spark session, however couldnt find any documentation about how to use it with the python spark api(pyspark).

would very much appriciate any guidence! using pyspark 2.4.4 version

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350115/how-to-register-a-sparklistener-to-work-on-spark-worker-process). I think your question is a duplicate of this.

Comment: thabks jacob, i already seen this but this isnt reffering to pyspark. how can i provide the plugin method from within python using pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for..You can set the property by using the `spark.executor.plugins` function.

```
spark=SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("test")
      .set("spark.executor.plugins", "")
```

Attaching screenshot for reference:

[image: Spark Conf using spark.executor.plugins]

Comment: what should i put as value of the executor.plugins?
a python file ? a python file that calls a relevant functino? a python class ?

Comment: basically you give the name of the plugin you want. I have seen Scala implementation for this, and I assume for PySpark python ones will work. Refer [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/) to know how to make python plugins.